# Speed of the object doesn't show even though the magnet already pass through to the hall sensor

Tags: c++, arduino

We're doing a project about detecting the speed of a vehicle all and our current problem is after the magnet already pass through to the hall sensor it only detects the magnet but doesn't show the speed of it. I hope you guys help me.

Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>


const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);
int hallsensor = 1;
int magnet = 0;
int count = 0;
int laststate = 1;

unsigned long currenttime = 0;
unsigned long revtime = 0;
unsigned long starttime = 0;
const unsigned long period = 1;

float motorspeed;
float radius = 0.2;
float pi = 3.14;
float wheel = 2*radius*pi;
float currentkph;

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  pinMode(hallsensor, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setTimeout(1);

  starttime = millis();
}

void loop() {
  currenttime = millis();
  magnet = digitalRead(hallsensor);

  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(currenttime/1000);
  //lcd.print(magnet);
  if (magnet == 1){
    laststate = 0;
    if(currenttime - starttime >= period && laststate == 0){
      revtime = currenttime - starttime;
      //motorspeed = (wheel/revtime)*1000;
      motorspeed = (3600000 / revtime)* wheel / 1000;
      currentkph = motorspeed;
      starttime = currenttime;
    
      lcd.setCursor(1, 0);
      lcd.print(currentkph);
      lcd.setCursor(8, 1);
      lcd.print("kph");
    }
    else{
      if(currenttime - starttime >= period && laststate == 0){
        starttime = currenttime;
        laststate = 1;
        lcd.setCursor(1, 0);
        lcd.print(currentkph);
        lcd.setCursor(8, 1);
        lcd.print("kph");
      }
    }
    lcd.setCursor(1, 0);
    lcd.print(currentkph);
  }
}
```

To help me fixed the error that I encountered.

Comment: if your code takes less than a millisecond to execute then `revtime` might be `0` and cause a crash. Also note that `3600000 / revtime` is an integer division which may not be what you want

Comment: Note that the code block on your `else { if { ....}` will never be executed. You start with an if after setting laststate to 0 and on your else-case you have the same if block, so the statement in your else will always be false.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more precise measurement I would recommend using an interrupt. You need to make sure to use an input pin that has interrupt capabilities, [have a look here](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/) for more information.

```
bool newTrigger = false;
unsigned long triggerTime = 0;
unsigned long oldTriggerTime = 0;

void setup() {
  ...
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(hallsensor), trigger, RISING);
  oldTriggerTime = millis();
}

void loop() {
  if (newTrigger) {
    unsigned long revtime = triggerTime - oldTriggerTime;
    oldTriggerTime = triggerTime;
    newTigger = false;
    // your calculations and LCD visualization
  }
}

void trigger() {
  newTrigger = true;
  triggerTime = millis();
}
```

For your code I can only make some guesses why it may not work:

1. You only read your hall sensor at the beginning of your `loop()`. If it triggers later, for example while controlling your LCD, you won't detect it. Depending on how long the HIGH on your input pin is, your chances of detecting it may be really small.
2. As in my comment noted, your else will never be executed
3. You set laststate to 0 before your if, so the `&& laststate == 0` part will always be true.
4. As Alan Birtles wrote, you may get some problems and precision problems with integer division. It is a tricky subject for beginners. I would recommend using float or double for such calculations:  `double motorspeed = (3600000.0 / (double)revtime)* (double)wheel / 1000.0;`

Comment: @CherryDT whoops you are right, fixed it.